# What's the proper way to work with 'react-leaflet' library in a react app made with 'create-react-app'?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, create-react-app, react-leaflet

i am getting troubles with **'react-leaflet'** library when i try to create a simple map component inside a react app made with **'create-react-app'** library, with no typescript nor flow.

the next code is a simple map component using **'react-leaflet'** with plain html and node_modules, i can't replicate it inside a **'create-react-app'** project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React-Leaflet UMD example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/react-leaflet/dist/react-leaflet.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 20px;
      }
      .leaflet-container {
        height: 400px;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2015,react">
    const React = window.React
const { Map: LeafletMap, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } = window.ReactLeaflet
const position = [51.505, -0.09]
const Example = () => (
  <LeafletMap center={position} zoom={13}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    <Marker position={position}>
      <Popup>
        <span>
          A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
        </span>
      </Popup>
    </Marker>
  </LeafletMap>
)
window.ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('container'))
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This (Maybe) should be the proper way to show the react-leaflet map component in a modularized and structured project like that.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';

class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (

      <div className="map">
        <Map center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} className="map__reactleaflet">
          <TileLayer
            url="https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>'
          />
        </Map>
      </div>

    )

  }

}

export default App;
```

> **'TileLayer'** is absolutely optional, you don't need this component to
>   render the map, but it's necessary to show the tiles on it, this means that you can
>   render a canvas with the cords as you wish, with markers, lines, polygons, or even nothing, you just need to import that component from **'react-leaflet'** library

If you find another or better solution, please share it, thanks!